# Why does Azure monitor say there are 26 requests (sum) when I am the only person accessing the web app and I look at 2 pages?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-monitoring

I am the only person who knows about my new Azure Blazor web app.  I browse to my app and look at two pages. The Azure monitor says there are a large numbers of requests at that moment in time (ranging from 7 to 26 to 66).  What is being counted as a request?  Why isn't the "request sum" closer to 2?
Sorry I can't give more details.  The Blazor app simply displays a list of 40 items and shows 3 images any time an item is selected in the list.

Comment: What do you mean when you write "I'm the only person who knows about ... app"?
Isn't it public? If so it can be found by bots via some DNS scanning.

Comment: I meant my app is not advertised or promoted at the moment, although anyone (including bots) can access it.  I looked at the Azure stats immediately after browsing to my website; I don't think bots are accessing at same time so I am the only one accessing the site at that time.  For my single browse, Azure stats show dozens of requests.  That is what confuses me.